# Почему к статическому методу можно обратиться через $this?

Tags: php

Есть код

```
Class A {
    public static function tableName() {
        return 'AAA';
    }
}

Class B extends A {
    public static function tableName() {
        return 'BBB';
    }

    public function test() {
        echo $this::tableName();
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->test();
```

Почему в версиях < PHP5.3  вызывало ошибку

> syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM, expecting ',' or ';' in **[...][...]** on line **18**

То есть на строке `$this::tableName()`

А начиная с 5.3 ошибок нет и отрабатывает корректно? Вплоть до PHP7.4. Ведь это некорректная запись. Есть какой-то глубинный смысл теперь в этом?

Comment: $this - содержит ссылку на класс и его свойства, вот и все. Т.е такая запись допускается. Хотя я бы использовал self, но разницы особой нет

Comment: @Node_pro да я тоже за применение self/static со статикой. А почему раньше это было запрещено и вызывало ошибку?

Comment: хорошо пораьотали с классами. Вот ссылочка `https://www.php.net/manual/ru/migration53.incompatible.php`